# LED drive circuit (PFET) turning ON by itself

Tags: led, fet

I thought 10k pull-up would prevent LED from turning on, but when I connect +VBAT (4V) and have D_LED_S_W floating the LED turns on slowly (in few seconds). When this happens the gate voltage starts decreasing from 3.2V and at about 2.8V LED is fully on.

What is happening here? I want to drive the LED with MCU GPIO. How can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is it a depletion-type P-channel MOSFET?

Comment: What is the voltage that the MCU is running on? Is it also at VBAT = 4 V? Also, there is no **current limiting resistor** present to limit the current through the LED. Powering a LED directly from 4 V is not recommended.

Comment: @ aschipfl:  PMV48XP,215 data sheet says this: "P-channel enhancement mode Field-Effect Transistor (FET) in a small SOT23 (TO-236AB) Surface-Mounted Device (SMD) plastic package usingTrench MOSFET technology."

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: D_LED_S_W is not connected to MCU when turning on happens so MCU voltage doesn´t have anything to do with this.

Comment: Do you contineously measuring the gate voltage? Because that makes D_LED_S_W is **not** floating.

Comment: Check that the 10k resistor is soldered correctly and actually is 10k. Also, add a current limit resistor in series with the LED before you damage it.

Comment: Have you checked accurately the pinout of the part and your layout? Just to rule out soldering/wiring mistakes. It would be nice if you added some photos of the real thing.